# Cant paint on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I am having a problem drawing a JLabel on my JFrame. I already did that in another project and it was working properly, but i messed up somewhere this time and cant draw anymore. Here is my Code:

Board:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Board extends JPanel {

public Board() {
    initBoard();
}

private void initBoard() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Frame.GAME_WIDTH, Frame.GAME_HEIGHT));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(Frame.GAME_WIDTH, Frame.GAME_HEIGHT));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Frame.GAME_WIDTH, Frame.GAME_HEIGHT));
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
  }
}
```

Frame:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public static final int GAME_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    private final String title = "title here";

    private Image backgroundIMG;

    public Frame() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        add(new Board());
        pack();
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(null);


        /*
         * set background image
         */
        /*try {
            this.backgroundIMG = ImageIO.read(new File("src/to/image"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();

        int titleWidth = 270;
        int titleHeight = 55;
        int titleX = 24;
        int titleY = 30;
        int titleSize = 47;
        String titleFont = "Ravie";

        /*
         * Customize the startscreen
         */
        JLabel title = new JLabel("text");
        title.setBounds(0, 0, titleWidth, titleHeight);
        title.setFont(new Font(titleFont, Font.BOLD, titleSize));
        title.setForeground(new Color(251,102,8));
        title.setLocation(titleX, titleY);
        add(title);
        System.out.println("title should be printed");
    }
}
```

Launcher:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Frame main = new Frame();
            main.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

When i start the program, the Frame is loading up but does not display the JLabel. Its also printing "title should be printed" on the console. I did some research already but wasnt able to find anything that helped me. Maybe its just a trivial error and someone can help me out real quick.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I add the Board to the JFrame, also its painting the background gray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting past all the, "interesting" stuff for moment, you're basic problem comes down to this...

```
add(new Board());
//... 
add(title);
```

Java/Swing paint's it's component in LIFO order, so the last component added, is the first component painted.

Probably the most logical fix is to add `title` to the `Board`, but you might want to fix a couple of other issues first...

- Avoid extending from top level containers like `JFrame`. Lots of reasons, but mostly, you're not adding new functionality to the class and it's locking you into a single use case which can be better managed through other means/components
- Avoid `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`. These are more trouble then they are worth.  Instead, as required, override `getPreferredSize`
- `setDoubleBuffered(true);` is pointless, as Swing components are double buffered by default
- Avoid `null` layouts, seriously, this is the number one cause of most of the issues people post about on SO.  The layout management API is there for a reason, learn to make use of it.

If we take all that into account, you might end up within something more like...

[image: Possible solution]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private final String title = "title here";

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame main = new JFrame(title);
            main.add(new MainPane());
            main.pack();
            main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            main.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static final int GAME_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

    public static class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private Image backgroundIMG;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            setBackground(Color.GRAY);

            add(new Board());

            String titleFont = "Ravie";
            int titleSize = 47;
            JLabel title = new JLabel("text");
            title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            title.setFont(new Font(titleFont, Font.BOLD, titleSize));
            title.setForeground(new Color(251, 102, 8));
            add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
    }

    public static class Board extends JPanel {

        public Board() {
            initBoard();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
        }

        private void initBoard() {
            setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: since I am just starting learning Java and its UI Components I really appreciate your answer and the improvements to my code. It helped me a lot.